# How to put javascript alert prompt before deleting value from angular multiselect

Tags: javascript, angular, multi-select

I need to put one alert prompt before removing value from list using `Angular2-multiselect`. I am explaining my code below.

```
<div class="form-field">
   <angular2-multiselect [data]="searchCoupon" #ProductCoupon formControlName="couponValues" [settings]="settings">
       <c-search>
           <ng-template>
                <input type="text" (keyup)="onCouponSearch($event)" placeholder="Search coupons" style="border: none;width: 100%; height: 100%;outline: none;"/>
           </ng-template>
      </c-search>
       <c-item>
          <ng-template let-item="item">
               <label style="color: #333;">{{item.CouponCode}}</label>
          </ng-template>
       </c-item>
       <c-badge>
          <ng-template let-item="item">
             <label style="margin: 0px;">{{item.CouponCode}}</label>
              <mat-icon matSuffix  (click)="editCoupon(item._id,true)" style="font-size: 17px;width: 15px;padding-left:5px;color:white">edit</mat-icon>
         </ng-template>
     </c-badge>  
     </angular2-multiselect>
</div>
```

Here I am using `Angular-multiselect` to select multiple items from list by search and this part is working fine. Here I need when user will remove any selected items one javascript alert prompt will display first if user will click on `ok` button then the selected item will be deleted other will it will not delete from the list.

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this you need to use `confirm(args)` which returns a `boolean` true when the user clicks ok and false if a user clicks on cancel.

You can use it like so,

```
const isOkDelete: boolean = confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this item?');

if (isOkDelete) {
   // delete this item...
} else {
   // do not delete this item...
}
```

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp for more information.

Comment: Did you get my question. I know this but here I am using the `angular2-multiselect` and this plugin deletes the selected value automatically. My question is how I can handle this inside confirm.

Comment: How are you handling the deletion? A user selects an item and then it deletes? What do you mean by automatic?

Comment: You should use `confirm()` wherever the code being executed to delete the item exists.

Comment: That plugin is deleting the selected value. There is no function written to delete the selected value. There you can find one `X` button on each selected item which is inbuilt and when user will select on that icon the value is deleting.

Comment: ```<angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" 
    [settings]="dropdownSettings" 
    (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" >...</angular2-multiselect>``` Have you used the `(onSelect)` event in your code? Like in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-multiselect-dropdown